# Gradle to add module dependency in Micronaut project

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have three module as shown below

[image]

The `fete-bird-apigateway` depend on common and `fete-bird-product` depend on both `fete-bird-apigateway` and `common`

In the fete-bird-product settings.gradle I have included the code below

```
    rootProject.name = "fete-bird-product"
include 'fete-bird-apigateway' , 'common'
```

and in the build.gradle of project

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':common')
}
```

**Error**

**Caused by: org.gradle.internal.component.NoMatchingConfigurationSelectionException: No matching configuration of project :common was found.**

I don't want to create a multi-module build project describe here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html. Each project should build individually and dependent modules should load while building.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Well I found that I had the wrong concept for different module projects.

Assuming all modules are part of the same multi-module build then in fete-bird-apigateway.gradle and service\build.gradle you add:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

dependencies {
  implementation project(':common')
}
```

However if common, fete-bird-apigateway and service are separate projects and don't share the same root build.gradle you have to publish the common module into a shared repository and use it like any regular dependency. Easiest to do with Maven Local repository.

To publish to the local maven

In `fete-bird-apigateway.gradle`

```
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'org.gradle.sample'
            artifactId = 'library'
            version = '1.1'

            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

Reference - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#gsc.tab=0

In the dependent project add the dependency as regular

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}

implementation("fete.bird:fete-bird-apigateway:0.1")
```

We need to run the task or gradle command for publish. I am using Intellj so did with below task

[image]

We can run the gradle command `gradle publishToMavenLocal`